# FineUploader and Mime type (------WebKitFormBoundary) appended into files

Tags: javascript, mime-types, fine-uploader

How to solve the problem of appended mime type in files uploaded with FINEUPLOADER tool when using Chrome or Firefox browser?
It happens both for binary and text file...
here below an example of uploaded text file.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCbkKYQSuaZj8PIIl
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

This is the begin of my text file...
...
...
This is the end of my text file...

------WebKitFormBoundaryCbkKYQSuaZj8PIIl--
```

Thanks!

Comment: The _problem_? That's how HTML forms are uploaded. If your issue is the _wrong_ MIME type...well you're right but it's a Chrome _bug_, what you may do is to inspect file extension and/or content at server side (anyway it's something you should always do, trusting client browser isn't a safe assumption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue here.  The files are sent, by default, in multipart encoded requests.  The file will be encased in a multipart boundary in the payload of this request, and the MIME type of the file will be specified as a parameter in the header of its multipart boundary.

You don't need to worry about any of this though, as there are libraries for every server side language in existence that parse multipart encoded requests.   If you are using PHP, MPE request parsing is built into the language in fact.

Comment: Yes, i see i have to check serverside. What i'm debugging is asp.net + Javascript and i'll try to parse MIME in some way. Internet Explorer, fortunately, does it for free. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those using the core options way, I had the same issue but after hours found that I needed to add the `omitDefaultParams` to the options.request object:

```
  const uploader = new FineUploader({
    options: {
      request: {
        method: ...,
        endpoint: ...,
        paramsInBody: false,
        forceMultipart: false,
        omitDefaultParams: true,
      },
    },
  });

  ...

  // assuming 'file' is a file in FileList
  uploader.methods.addFiles(file);
```

I hope this saves someone a few hours.